# Proper way to set up "Pac-Man" contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{1+x} \: dx, \: -1<a<0
$$

using contour integrals.  Actually, I have found the correct answer using a "Pac-Man" contour and residues.  My only question concerns the correct way to take the limit of the contour.  Suppose it has inner radius $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, outer radius $R \to \infty$, and it "eats" the positive x-axis with a "bite angle" of $2 \alpha \downarrow 0$.  It seems to me that the right way to do things is to let $\alpha \downarrow 0$, then $\epsilon \downarrow \infty, R \to \infty$.  Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "eating" the positive x-axis with a "bite angle" of 2α↓0? I think you only need the inner radius and outer radius.

Comment: If you only use inner and outer radius, then you have to have to deal with the segments along the x-axis.  How does one precisely do this? (This is an old qual question, so that is why I am trying to make my answer as precise as possible.)

Comment: Alternately, let $t=\dfrac1{1+x}$, and recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral. Then, by expressing it in terms of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties), and using Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula), rewrite it in terms of elementary trigonometric functions.

Comment: Change variable to get $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{1+x}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{2\alpha +1}}{1+t^2}dt$. I think is is easier to deal with. If you want to use rasidue calculus, you only need the inner and outer radius.

Comment: I am not looking for an alternative way.  My question is simply about how to deal with this technicality of taking the limit of a contour.  Most books seem to wave hands regarding this point.

Comment: Yes, your approach is reasonable. It works.